# Redshift COPY command gets stuck because of locks

Tags: python, amazon-redshift, amazon-redshift-serverless

I'm trying to use a python script using the redshift_connector library to perform multiple COPY commands from S3 and possibly DELETE commands - all on the same redshift table. I'm using serverless redshift.

The commands on redshift gets stuck because of locks - they work from time to time but mostly I find the following locks in redshift:

1. ShareRowExclusiveLock
2. AccessShareLock

Both are locks on the table I work with, and the only way I found to end the process is by calling the locks_to_release stored procedure

Here is how my code looks like:

```
with redshift_connector.connect(...) as cnn:
    with cnn.cursor() as cursor:
         cursor.execute("DELETE FROM my_table WHERE ...'")
         cursor.execute("COPY my_table FROM 's3://my_bucket/my_folder/' IAM_ROLE 'my-role' FORMAT AS PARQUET")
```

Comment: Are you committing your changes?

Comment: yes, I tried both auto commit and running commit manually after running the commands

Comment: “Gets stuck” means that they serialize or do they actually deadlock?  You will likely need to post the locks transaction ids to figure out what is causing a deadlock

Comment: Data is not serialized - what you mean by posing the transaction ids?

Comment: The system table pg_locks has info about who makes the lock and what type.  This page may help - https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/prevent-locks-blocking-queries-redshift/ .  You can use system tables to track down which queries are making which locks on which table.  Each connection to redshift will have a unique session id and each lock will be associated with a transaction id (xid).  This links things together.  To figure this out will likely need tracking down what is causing the stoppage.